# Refactoring common code from exception section

Tags: java, refactoring

I have following code with repeated code so I am doing something wrong and there must be better way of doing this. I have common set of statement in the catch section. I can't put this in finally block as these are done for exception scenario only. Other than making separate method to hold this code is there any other approach I can take?

```
public MyResponseDto doSomeWork(MyRequestDto) {
  ....
  String jsonStr = null;
  try {
    jsonStr = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(MyRequestDto);
  } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
    log.error(e.getMessage());
    myResponseDto .setWorkDone(false);
    myResponseDto .setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
    return myResponseDto ;
  } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    log.error(e.getMessage());
    myResponseDto .setWorkDone(false);
    myResponseDto .setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
    return myResponseDto ;
  } catch (IOException e) {
    log.error(e.getMessage());
    myResponseDto .setWorkDone(false);
    myResponseDto .setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
    return myResponseDto ;
  }

  myResponseDto = postWorkRequest(jsonStr);
  return myResponseDto ;

}
```

Comment: Multi-exception catch? What's wrong with making a method, anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public MyResponseDto doSomeWork(MyRequestDto) {
  ....
  String jsonStr = null;
  try {
    jsonStr = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(MyRequestDto);
  } catch (JsonGenerationException | JsonMappingException e) {
    log.error(e.getMessage());
    myResponseDto .setWorkDone(false);
    myResponseDto .setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
    return myResponseDto ;
  } 
  myResponseDto = postWorkRequest(jsonStr);
  return myResponseDto ;
}
```

This is how you catch multiple Exceptions in one `catch`. You can try it for the rest, hope that helps. Off course you can put more than 2 Exception in one catch!

EDIT: please note that this will only work for Java 7 or newer

Comment: I believe OP doesn't ask for < 7 solutions..?

Comment: Not sure what you meant.. The multicatch  feature is since java 7. Mentioning that in answer will make it clear.

Comment: I edited the answer. I know it useful but on the other hand when someone advises to use generics usually they don't mention that it's only for Java 5 or newer, right? :)

Comment: Why can't I have catch (JsonGenerationException | JsonMappingException | IOException e)?

Comment: Generally Exceptions in one catch cannot be in the same inheritance tree, so no you can't. IOException will have to be in separate catch and it will have to be after the catch with two others, otherwise you'll gt a compiler error

Comment: so having only catch (IOException e) will be enough?

Comment: Yes it will :) Especially since you handle them all the same, there is no need to know which particular Exception was thrown

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Java 7 you can use the try-multi catch. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html